# Why should we use "::" operator on global functions / objects?

Tags: c++, syntax

I have seen this used in various places. C++ programmers will often use the :: operator right before a global function call.

e.g

```
::glGenBuffers( 1, &id );
```

Why is this? Why not just use:

```
glGenBuffers( 1, &id );
```

Comment: Personally, I never would use leading :: in my code. If I have a namespace overriding the global with duplicate definitions then I probably meant to do that. Using :: all of the time when not needed is like writing `this->variable` instead of `variable` in class functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid accidental namespace clashing. For example if you current namespace would have `glGenBuffers` which does something different from the "good" `glGenBuffers` with `::` you can specify to call the `glGenBuffers` which is in the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is 1) names in inner scopes hide names in outer scopes and 2) there can be ambiguous of function calls when using directive is used.

For example (ambiguity)

```
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void swap( int &x, int &y )
{
   int tmp = x;
   x = y;
   y = tmp;
}

int main()
{
   int x = 5, y = 10;

   //swap( x, y ); compiler error: what function to call?

   ::swap( x, y ); // the user defined function is called

   std::swap( x, y ); // the standard function is called.
}
```

Another example of hidding names

```
#include <iostream>

void f() { std::cout << "::f()\n"; }

namespace MyNamespace
{
   void f() { std::cout << "MyNamespace::f()\n"; }

   void g() { f(); } // calls MyNamespace::f()

   void h() { ::f(); } // calls ::f()
}


int main()
{
   MyNamespace::g();
   MyNamespace::h();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here [C++ Scope Resolution Operator ::](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc05cplr175.htm)

> The :: (scope resolution) operator is used to qualify hidden names so
>   that you can still use them. You can use the unary scope operator if a
>   namespace scope or global scope name is hidden by an explicit
>   declaration of the same name in a block or class.

Answer (score 1):

`::glGenBuffers` to force choose the method in global namespace

```
void method()
{
    std::cout << "method in global namespace";
}

class Test {
    void method() 
    {
        std::cout << "method in Test class";
    }

    void test()
    {
        method(); // method in Test class
        ::method(); //method in global namespace
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly marking the scope may save you from unexpected matches through using declarations or argument dependent lookup. For example, consider the following:

```
namespace foo
{
  class X {};
  void bar(X*, int):
}

// ... much in between ...

foo::X some_object

// ... more in between ...

void bar(X*, long);

int main()
{
  bar(&some_object, 42); // calls foo::bar, because it is a better match
  ::bar(&some_object, 42); // calls ::bar, because it is explicitly told to
}
```

If you were not aware that there is a `bar` in namespace `foo`, or that `some_object` has a type from namespace `foo`, the call to `foo::bar` instead of `::bar` may catch you by surprise.

Answer (score 0):

The scope operator (`::`) is used for accessing the global namespace on 2 occasions mainly:

a) importing a global method / variable / typedef (from global namespace) into a namespace:

```
int fun()
    {
    return 1;
    }

namespace x
    {
    using ::fun; 
    // you cannot do `using fun`, as using requires a namespace after
    // in this case, we are `using` the global namespace
    }

int main()
    {
    std::cout << fun() + x::fun(); // prints 2
    }
```

**Edit**: This is done by some `STL` implementations, for example: `std::size_t`:

```
typedef unsigned int size_t;

namespace std
    {
    using ::size_t;
    }

size_t x = 1;
std::size_t y = 2;
```

b) To avoid clashing:

```
# include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<class T> inline
    void swap(T &left, T &right)
    {
    T tmp = left;
    left = right;
    right = tmp;
    }

int main()
    {
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    // swap(a, b) - error: which 'swap'?
    std::swap(a, b); // the one in <algorithm>
    ::swap(a, b); // the one i defined
    }
```

- Note: `using namespace std;` is not a reccomended practise.

**Edit**

MSVC compiler provides the `_CSTD` macro (`#define _CSTD ::`), so that you can use `using _CSTD fun;`, e.t.c instead if you prefer.